# Passing state to children with react navigation and redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have main screen which have data and I wanna pass that data to comments page on press.
I used react navigation and redux for navigation. My senior said to make reducer and pass state but I dont know how to do. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.dispatch({type: NAV_COMMENTS})}
```

Answer (score 0):

When this action "NAV_COMMENTS" is fired store the values in Store (reducer of that parent component) that you want to pass in the child component and access them in child component like (this.props.value...)